# 2 var arrays change mysteriously after i change arrayToDataTable input (google chart line)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, google-visualization

I'm displaying a line chart of currency rates via [google charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart).

Basically i have 2 type of values:

1. Date (format iso8601)
2. Rate (decimal number)

i'm trying to impelement a function that changes the input of arrayToDataTable:

```
    dataChart = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayForChart);
```

basically im changing the role of base currency between the 2 currencies.
the line chart should reverse everytime i do that.

when i'm pressing on the change display button once ('currencyRates_changeDisplay'), its changes the graph. he graph is reversed and everything is ok.
but after that the graph is stuck with the values of the last change. and the google chart line will not change any more.

i did some debugging.

it seems that the "var arrayForChart" and "var arrayTest" change to the value of "var arrayChanegeDisplaySettingForChart" after i press the button "#currencyRates_changeDisplay" once. and they do not change anymore after that.
i think it is because of this line:

```
    dataChart = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayForChart);
```

but i'm not sure. here is my full code:

```
    <script>

    var arrayForChart;
    var arrayTest;
    var checkkk=0;

    var arrayChanegeDisplaySettingForChart;

    var dataChart;


    var baseCurrencyDisplaySetting=1;     
    var baseCurrency="USD";


    var dayResults;
    var yesterdayResults;


    var fromCurrency;
    var toCurrency;
    var currencyAmount;


    var direction;
    var percent;
    var gainLoss;

    loadRates();

    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {

        if (baseCurrencyDisplaySetting==2){
            arrayChanegeDisplaySettingForChart=arrayForChart;
            arrayChanegeDisplaySettingForChart=changeArrayForChart(arrayChanegeDisplaySettingForChart);
        }
        whenAjaxReallyStops();

    });
    function whenAjaxReallyStops() {

            //alert("AJAX REALLY ENDED");                   
            displayCurrencyConverterResult();
            dipsplayChart();
            displayAllRates();


    }

    function loadRates(){
        baseCurrency   = $("#baseCurrency").val();
        fromCurrency   = $("#currency_from").val();
        toCurrency   = $("#currency_to").val();
        currencyAmount = $("#currency_amount").val();


    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "just a url here...",
    data: {
    baseCurrency: baseCurrency,
    toCurrency: toCurrency
            },
    cache: false
        }).done(function(data) {

            resultArray=data;
            dayResults=resultArray["0"];
            yesterdayResults=resultArray["1"];
            console.log(dayResults);
            console.log(yesterdayResults);
            arrayTest=resultArray["arrayForCharts"];
            arrayForChart=resultArray["arrayForCharts"];
            alert ("arrayForChart changed");
            console.log(resultArray);

        });
    }


    function changeArrayForChart(changedArrayForChart){

        console.log(changedArrayForChart);
        for (var key in changedArrayForChart) {     
            if (key != 0){
                let newRateForChart=1*(1 / changedArrayForChart[key][1]);
                changedArrayForChart[key][1]=newRateForChart;
            }
        }
        return changedArrayForChart;    
    }
    function dipsplayChart(){
        //from here google chart stuff
        google.charts.load("current", {packages: ["corechart", "line"]});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawLineColors);


        //until here google chart stuff
    }

    function drawLineColors() {
        dataChart=null;
        if (baseCurrencyDisplaySetting==1){
            if (checkkk==0){
                    console.log (JSON.stringify(arrayForChart));
                dataChart = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayForChart);
            }else{
                    console.log (JSON.stringify(arrayTest));
                dataChart = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayTest);
            }
            checkkk=checkkk+1;
            var titleChartString = baseCurrency + " vs " + toCurrency + " Last 90 days";
        }else{
                console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayChanegeDisplaySettingForChart));            
dataChart = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayChanegeDisplaySettingForChart);
            var titleChartString = toCurrency + " vs " + baseCurrency + " Last 90 days";
        }       
        var options = {
    title: titleChartString ,
    explorer: {
    actions: ["dragToZoom", "rightClickToReset"],
    axis: "horizontal",
    keepInBounds: true
            },
    hAxis: {
    title: "Date",
    format: "d MMM",

            },
    vAxis: {
    title: "Rate",
            },
    colors: ["#a52714", "#097138"]
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("chart_div"));
        chart.draw(dataChart, options);
    }           

    $("body").on( "click", "#currencyRates_changeDisplay", function(){
        if (baseCurrencyDisplaySetting==1){
            baseCurrencyDisplaySetting=2;
            if (typeof arrayChanegeDisplaySettingForChart == "undefined"){
                arrayChanegeDisplaySettingForChart=arrayForChart;
                arrayChanegeDisplaySettingForChart=changeArrayForChart(arrayChanegeDisplaySettingForChart);
            }
        }else{
            baseCurrencyDisplaySetting=1;
        }
        displayAllRates();
        dipsplayChart();
    });                     

    </script>
```

here are sample data:

arrayForChart:

```
[[{"label":"Date","id":"Date","type":"date"},{"label":"Rate","id":"Rate","type":"number"}],["Date(2017, 3, 10)",3.6618],["Date(2017, 3, 11)",3.6565]]
```

then i press the button 'currencyRates_changeDisplay'.

i get this notice in console log:

```
[Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive.
```

arrayChanegeDisplaySettingForChart:

```
[[{"label":"Date","id":"Date","type":"date"},{"label":"Rate","id":"Rate","type":"number"}],["Date(2017, 3, 10)",0.2730897372876727],["Date(2017, 3, 11)",0.2734855736359907]]
```

then i press the button 'currencyRates_changeDisplay' again.

arrayTest:

```
[[{"label":"Date","id":"Date","type":"date"},{"label":"Rate","id":"Rate","type":"number"}],["Date(2017, 3, 10)",0.2730897372876727],["Date(2017, 3, 11)",0.2734855736359907]
```

from here, evrytime i press the butoon 'currencyRates_changeDisplay': 'arrayTest' and 'arrayForChart' are stuck with the values of 'arrayChanegeDisplaySettingForChart' and the chart never change.

Anybody might know what is the problem?

many thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is instructing to only call `changeArrayForChart` when `arrayChanegeDisplaySettingForChart` is undefined. Therefore this only happens once, as after the first time, that latter variable is no longer undefined.

So change this:

```
if (baseCurrencyDisplaySetting==1){
    baseCurrencyDisplaySetting=2;
    if (typeof arrayChanegeDisplaySettingForChart == "undefined"){
        arrayChanegeDisplaySettingForChart=arrayForChart;
        arrayChanegeDisplaySettingForChart=changeArrayForChart(arrayChanegeDisplaySettingForChart);
    }
}else{
    baseCurrencyDisplaySetting=1;
}
```

To:

```
// For arrays you can just use `!` to test for not being defined:
if (!arrayChanegeDisplaySettingForChart) {
    // This happens only once:
    arrayChanegeDisplaySettingForChart = arrayForChart;
}
// Now toggle. Note that changeArrayForChart mutates the given array
// so you don't need the return value 
changeArrayForChart(arrayChanegeDisplaySettingForChart);
// A way to toggle between 1 and 2:
baseCurrencyDisplaySetting = 3 - baseCurrencyDisplaySetting;
```

Comment: i'm still trying to fully understand your code. can you please give me a tutorial article the will explain to me this line: "// Now toggle. Note that changeArrayForChart mutates the given array
// so you don't need the return value 
changeArrayForChart(arrayChanegeDisplaySettingForChart);"

Comment: Your function has this line: `changedArrayForChart[key][1]=newRateForChart`. This means the array that you have given as argument is *modified* (mutated). So, when that function finishes, the array you passed to it, has already changed. You could still assign the array that the function returns back to your array, but that really does not change anything: the array had already changed. See for instance [this article](http://orizens.com/wp/topics/javascript-arrays-passing-by-reference-or-by-value/) which may help to grasp this.